# Web config encryption using DataProtectionConfigurationProvider is not working on Production

Tags: asp.net, encryption, iis-8, webconfigurationmanager, web-config-encryption

I have used **DataProtectionConfigurationProvider** to encrypt the connection strings of web config, which is working fine in local.

But when I uploaded the code to production, the web config is not getting encrypted.

I have used following code:

```
Configuration config =
                WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
            // Let's work with the <connectionStrings> section
            ConfigurationSection connectionStrings = config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
            if (connectionStrings != null)
            {

                // Only encrypt the section if it is not already protected
                if (!connectionStrings.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
                {
                  // Encrypt the <connectionStrings> section using the 
                    // DataProtectionConfigurationProvider provider
                    connectionStrings.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(
                        "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
                    config.Save();
                }
            }
```

I traced the code by putting the logs and found that **!connectionStrings.SectionInformation.IsProtected** condition is not working .

Any help would be appreciable!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to "/" path in **WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/")**. My application is hosted inside virtual directory.

Using below code solved the issue:

```
  Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
```